# PHP MYSQL Relations

Tags: php

Всем привет у меня есть таблица со структурой (id,title,parent_id)
Как с точки зрения кода правильнее всего вывести категория/подкатегория?

Comment: тут рекурсивный обход, других вариантов нету.

Comment: Не рекурсия сложно дебажиться и много запросов, можно сделать join таблицы саму на себя и отсортировав получить последовательный массив с подкатегориями, ну это если нужна всего одна. А в общем есть алгоритм использующий левый и правый id категории, после чего можно слёгкостью определить в каком месте есть елемент.

Comment: при рекурсии нет никаких вложенных запросов если правильно включить мозг. С дуру можно и что угодно сломать. Человек вроде не спрашивал про nested sets, да и если он не знает как ему отрендерить эту структуру, в nested sets он точно не разберется.

Comment: А как правильнее всего реализовать отношение Категория/Подкатегория? Создать две таблицы? или одну и потом уже обрабатывать все это?

Comment: это уже другой вопрос, оформлять его надо отдельно наверное, а на этот вопрос ответ вроде как дан.

Answer (score 1):

Для структуры типа (id,name,parent_id)

Вот пример выборки:

```
//Выбираем данные из БД
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  categories");
//Если в базе данных есть записи, формируем массив
if   (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $cats = array();
//В цикле формируем массив разделов, ключом будет id родительской категории, а также массив разделов, ключом будет id категории
    while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $cats_ID[$cat['id']][] = $cat;
        $cats[$cat['parent_id']][$cat['id']] =  $cat;
    }
}
```

Вот функция построения дерева.

```
function build_tree($cats,$parent_id,$only_parent = false){
if(is_array($cats) and isset($cats[$parent_id])){
    $tree = '<ul>';
    if($only_parent==false){
        foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
            $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'].' #'.$cat['id'];
            $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
    }elseif(is_numeric($only_parent)){
        $cat = $cats[$parent_id][$only_parent];
        $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'].' #'.$cat['id'];
        $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
        $tree .= '</li>';
    }
    $tree .= '</ul>';
}
else return null;
return $tree;
}
```